# Rule of inference. Is the argument valid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Show that the following argument is valid by using rules of inference.
>
> The premises are:
>
> 1. $\neg p \vee r$
> 2. $q \rightarrow (k \wedge t)$
> 3. $p \rightarrow q$
> 4. $\neg(k \wedge t)$
>
> The conclusion is: $r$

I was unable to solve this question but my lecturer said there is nothing wrong with this question. So, is the above argument valid? Please give your answer with prove and explanation.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is not valid.

The second, third, and fourth premises entail $\neg p$ ... via *modus tollens*.

$$p\to q, q\to(k\wedge t), \neg(k\wedge t)\vdash \neg p$$

So *any* interpretation which satisfies these three premises will also satisfy the first premise.

However, notice that *their* valuation is *not* dependent on the valuation of $r$.

Thus we may value $r$ as false in *some* interpretations where all four premises are satisfied.

Therefore $r$ is *not* entailed by these four premises.

Answer (score 1):

This argument is invalid. Multiple applications of Modus Tollens on 2, 3, 4 leads to $\neg p$.

Hence 1 always holds and no conclusion can be drawn on $r$.

Another way to show that this is invalid is via truth tables.

As long as $p=q=k=t=F$, $r$ can be $T$ or $F$.

The mistake in the question is either 1 should be $(p \lor r)$ or $(\neg p \to r)$ (which are equivalent to each other.)